# Is there an "Edit Message" keyboard shortcut in MS Teams?

Tags: microsoft-teams

I often discover immediately after I send a chat message in MS Teams that I've typed something wrong. It takes ages to go to the "..." menu, select Edit, edit the message and resubmit, and often by the time I've done that the recipient has already read the wrong message.

Is there a keyboard shortcut that can get me straight into editing mode?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After you send the message just press the **UP Arrow** key and it will put you straight into the edit mode.

Comment: This. But be careful, wait until the text box goes into edit mode before you start typing. The cursor starts on the left by default, then magically moves to the end after ~ 0.5 seconds.

Comment: Brilliant, I'm glad that it's so simple as well, I couldn't find it in the documentation. Thanks!

Comment: This is a bit painful but if the message is not the most recent one in the thread to use Up Array with... You can 1) Select Message by method of choice 2) Press Enter > Tab > Enter > Down Arrow > Enter.   Assuming Edit is the second item in the Context menu of the message.

Comment: How about when the comment is selected? It has border around iteself. Using arrow keys I can move among other comments. I would expect some key to enable the edit messsage mode. (The up arrow works for me for the first time only. After pressing enter and then Arrow Up the message is selected instead of edit mode.)